# glassfish4.1.1 "A full JDK (not just JRE) is required"

Tags: glassfish-4.1.1

Windows 10: installed glassfish4.1.1 and jdk-8u111 but having the "A full JDK (not just JRE) is required" problem. The path variable looks ok as does the JAVA_HOME variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need JDK not the JRE, JDK has the tools javac.exe, java.exe, jar.exe, etc.
Make sure you have downloaded JDK and set the PATH to point to the jdk/bin folder